# Reconstruct shape of a body from rationality of its projections

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

1. There is a closed convex body $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Areas of its projections on all planes (not only those normal to axes $x,y,z$) are *rational* numbers. Can we deduce that $S$ is a ball?
2. Replace *rational* with *irrational* in the first question.

Comment: By continuity aren’t both hypotheses equivalent to the hypothesis that all projections have the *same* area? The answer to the two-dimensional analogue is *no* (curves of constant width), but I don’t know whether that generalizes to $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Brian M. Scott observes the orthogonal projections must all have the same area.  Solids where all the projections are of constant area are known as bodies of constant brightness, and non-spherical bodies of constant brightness are known.  The first discovered is known as a Blaschke-Firey body and is something like the body of rotation of a Reuleaux triangle.

An out of date introduction is the article [Shapes of the Future](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3026963) by Victor Klee.

Comment: I got curious and did a little searching. References and a minimality result can be found in [this paper](http://www.springerlink.com/index/VG18GAUDWFRQUPM3.pdf) by Paolo Gronchi. In [this paper](http://www.math.sc.edu/~howard/Reprints/published_brightness.pdf) Ralph Howard shows that balls are the only convex bodies with constant brightness *and* constant width.