# Surfaces of constant projected area

Tags: solid-geometry

Generalizing the well-known variety of plane [curves of constant width](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_of_constant_width), I'm wondering about three-dimensional surfaces of constant projected area.

**Question:** If $A$ is a (bounded) subset of $\mathbb R^3$, homeomorphic to a closed ball, such that the orthogonal projection of $A$ onto a plane has the same area for all planes, is $A$ necessarily a sphere? If not, what are some other possibilities?

Wikipedia mentions a concept of convex shapes with constant *width*, but that's different.

(Inspired by the discussion about spherical cows in comments to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/154221/14366) -- my question is seeking to understand whether there are other shapes of cows that would work just as well).

Comment: This is explicitly not what you want to know, but there's such a beautiful thread on MO about shapes with spherical projections http://mathoverflow.net/questions/39127/ that it would be a pity not to mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called bodies of *constant brightness*. A convex body that has both constant width *and* constant brightness is a Euclidean ball. But non-spherical convex bodies of constant brightness do exist; the first was found by Blaschke in 1916. See: Google and related [MSE thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89558/reconstruct-shape-of-a-body-from-rationality-of-its-projections).

Comment: Thanks. My google-fu is not strong enough to find an image of Blaschke's body (though there are many places referencing it). Do you know any?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I stole [this image](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/29863189/Blaschke_body.png) from page 113 of the very interesting book [Geometric Tomography](http://books.google.com/books/about/Geometric_Tomography.html?id=hwcKEZNLEmUC) by Rochard Gardner.